# How can we prove the following matrices inequality?

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, inequality, normed-spaces

Let $A$ and $B$ be two matrices $(nxn)$. How can we prove the following inequality? I have really no idea about how to prove it. Can you give me some hints?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be false. A counter-example is: $n=4$, $B=2I_4$, $A=I_4$, and $\|M\|=\max_{\|x\|_2=1} \frac{\|Mx\|_2}{\|x\|_2}$.
Then $(A+B)^n-A^n=(3^n-1) I_4$. So, $\|(A+B)^n-A^n\|=3^4-1$.

And $\|B\|\|A\|^{n-1}e^{\frac{\|B\|}{\|A\|}}=2e^2<3^4-1$.